# Why Can't I duck reverb on the mix bus in Unity?

Tags: unity, audio

i'm surprised there is so little documentation on this issue. But i'm trying to duck the audio on all the mix buses in Unity so that you can clearly hear the VO of the game.

Now it works great except that I have some reverb zones in the game and any sound that plays in these reverb zones, the actual reverb itself is NOT DUCKED.

So the VO is accompanied with a huge wall of wishy washy muddy noise.

Anyone deal with this before? How can we deal with this?

Comment: what does "duck" mean in this context?

Comment: @Evorlor (and everyone else): to "duck" audio means to reduce the volume temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible in Unity, at least as far as I know. The reverb zone is a component independent of the Audio Mixer, just as Audio Sources by default. You can set an Audio Mixer for Audio Sources, but not for Reverb Zones.

[This forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/reverb-question.290102/) may help you. User ShapeFarm said this:

> We're using snapshots (that triggers when you go through different areas) in Unity 5 to change reverb settings etc. Works very nice! It's especially useful for the EQ and filter DPS's at disposal.

The previous post only helps us to corroborate the above, but it also helps us a bit to find a solution.

By using Audio Mixer's features, you could trigger certain Snapshots with certain audio filters (like reverb) instead of relying on Reverb Zones. This way, you could definitively play your VO without being affected by reverb zones.